# Wavelets frame for $L^2[0,\infty)$

Tags: wavelet

I need a wavelet frame for $L^2[0,\infty)$. Moreover, the wavelet should be twice differentiable and with continuous second order derivatives. Hopefully, the wavelet should have compact support (either in the time-domain or in the frequency-domain). Is there such a wavelet?

Previously I had asked similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109503/what-other-wavelets-besides-the-haar-system-form-a-basis-of-l20-1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109447/is-there-a-wavelet-basis-for-l20-infty). However I think this question fits well here.

Thanks.

Comment: In Daubechies' "Ten lectures on wavelets", section 10.7, an orthonormal wavelet basis for $L_2[0,\infty]$ is constructed, some references are given. Have you seen this?

Comment: sorry for wrong ] bracket :-)